# Winecfg doesn't run anymore on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: wine

Winecfg doesn't launch anymore so my games either. I think it doesn't work since I changed the windows version on wine to windows 98 instead of windows xp. How can I change it please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove your .wine configuration folder. Warning: if you installed any important programs in Wine's "C:" drive make a backup first. Open a terminal and run:

`mv .wine .wine.bak`

`winecfg`

Now Wine configuration should create a new wineprefix and open.